# VNC freeze when switching screens on MacOS

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I am connecting to macOS (Catalina 10.15.17) to remotely manage it. Connected from Ubuntu ( using Remmina & windows using tight VNC but same problem)

If I continue using mac remotely without switching between maximized windows of mac, it works fine,
But as soon I try to switch between for example maximized window of mail app and safari app the screen always hangs and freezes without recovery, unless I reconnect vnc client
Sharing a screen of when it hangs up, in the middle of switching two maximized screens while switching to other screen.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

**MORE INFORMATION**
The actual mouse pointer on the real machine (macOS) continues to move and clicks etc work, but on the client side image remains frozen as in screen shot.

Comment: Have you had a lot of apps opened while doing this?

Comment: @Thinkr No, not many apps.

Comment: I suggest you update your device and try again, you can make an edit of your question with the result.

Comment: [VNC is a horrible tool](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277134/119271).  You’d be better off with something  like TeamViewer.  I long ago switched to CLI mode for nearly everything remote to my Mac,