Can you get 1440p on external monitor via Mini DisplayPort to HDMI converter on MacBook Air (mid 2012)?
Is it possible to get 1440p over an adapter (Mini DisplayPort to HDMI) on an external display on MacBook Air (2012)?
The adapter supports 4k, and the HDMI cable does too. Still, I don't get the 2560x1440 option when Option-clicking Scaled or Detect Displays in System Preferences. I am on Catalina, the latest for this Mac model.
I am thinking about getting a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort 1.2 instead since my monitor has a DisplayPort input. I have run 1440p via a PC on this monitor before, so I know it works via HDMI.
Before I buy another cable that I would never use for anything else, I want to know if there is something else that could be causing this, or if it is possible that you cannot get those resolutions via adapter on such an old Mac.
I saw a similar post with no replies, it was a few years old so I decided to make a new one.

You don't say which MBA 2012 you have. Assuming the i7 model you may be able to get that resolution (https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i7-2.0-13-mid-2012-specs.html) but you may need to do a little fiddling: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73177/how-to-change-resolution-when-using-screen-sharing-and-no-physical-screen-is-con#73696 Or possibly even seek out shareware utilities that allow you to set any resolution.
