# Best way to connect Remote Mac with audio from Mac or PC

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, screen-sharing, apple-remote-desktop

I am in a need of a solution, where I can remotely connect from my PC/Mac to remote Mac Pro or Mac mini with audio coming from it.  I will be using VPN to access Remote Mac, so I couldn't get Airfoil working for me (correct me if I missed something from the tool). I went through several tools such as nuoRDS, SoundFlower (didn't work on Catalina), VNC Pro (paid one also didn't work for macOS).

Any ideal solution that would help me as I am looking for 10-15 users. So purchasing one tool or a year license would be a solution too but per month, per user, per session is quite out of context.

Please suggest anything that you recommend, I will test it.

Comment: Will all users get the same audio stream from the remote Mac, or individual ones? Do the users have individual account on the remote Mac?

Comment: Also how does the audio stream get created, what plays the audio? Why can‘t you just run a web server on the remote which streams the audio files? It will be easier to find good solutions if you add some details about the context and the use cases.

Comment: @nohillside   It's like a scenario where I have to provide the user a way to work from home. There are many users with macOS and they have mac mini/mac Pro in the office with different audio files. So, once they are connected to VPN, there are many tools to access remote mac machine but I am looking with audio that plays on the remote machine. Audio can be mp3, wav and they use VLC or different licensed media players as per recording. They should be able to hear this audio coming from remote macOS while working from home

Comment: copy files from the remote machine are not useable in this scenario.

Comment: [Is there a remote desktop solution that will transfer sound output to the client?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7941/18101)

Comment: @Nic: I have been through this before writing here. I have checked each and every tool that I can see on Google's first page. I need a audio from a remote Mac machine to end the machine (PC/Mac). ARD and VNC don't support the audio beside that there were no issue on such tool.

Comment: Yes, testing now with Loopback, Audio Hijack ( i think it is more for recording). I haven't been through the Twitch stream. I have to look at this too. I am looking for 50-60 users so a stable solution is must be needed. I will have a bunch of media files playing on a mac, maybe from Safari or VLC and need to listen to it from remote machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105359/discussion-between-nic-and-udhy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be helpful for everyone if you are looking for something for paid solutions.

I have found a very nice tool named [**SplashTop**](https://www.splashtop.com/business).

https://www.splashtop.com/business

**Why transmitting audio is not so easy in macOS:**

> Apple has discontinued the support of user-space audio plugins (HAL).
>   Without this functionality, we can not capture audio from user
>   session. The method proposed by Apple (Audio Server) captures audio
>   from a single user session on console only.  Therefore all old tool
>   does not support audio redirection.

I have tested with FreeTrial on it and it works perfectly as I am looking for. No need to hijack or route audio from any third party.

Comment: As a point of interest, it looks like Splashtop is using [tag:soundflower] under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

There's an incredible FOSS for P2P Mac audio streaming called [SonoBus](https://sonobus.net). SonoBus in conjunction with a virtual audio driver like [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/blob/master/LICENSE) (also FOSS), is the best solution I've found for streaming HQ audio.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duck tape solution, but worked for my purposes.

Open a zoom meeting on the remote computer using remote desktop.

Open the application from which you wish to here audio

Share the screen for the audio generating app on zoom, making sure to check the options in the lower left hand corner that allow sound to pass thru.

Join the zoom meeting from the computer from which you wish to listen

If you have an excellent internet connection this is a pretty cheap and easy way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and found this workaround

1. Install a virtual audio device on the Mac OS device. In my case, it was [soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/).
2. Update the mac settings to use this virtual driver as output.
3. On the mac device, join a Google Meet room and select the soundflower as the input device.
4. Join the same Google Meet room from your local computer.

Now you should be able to hear sounds from the Mac OS via google meet.